# Add a page option in the "edit page" form in the backend of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In the backend of Wordpress,
 -in the "edit page" page, 
  -more specifically in the "page option" area,

I would like to include a custom option (let's say option1).  I want to reuse this option in my theme template files (page.php) to modify the way the page is generated.  How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: use custom fields http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: ...and to retrieve that information in your templates use get_post_meta() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta - If you get stuck I'll write an example out.

Comment: It did solve my solution, thanks.  I was looking in stuff way more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom field name + value with your page. Then in the page template use this:

```
$meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );
```